# Why can methods of subclasses be more accessible?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

A quick example

```
class A {
    protected int foo(int x){
        return x;   
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int foo(int x){
        return x*x; 
    }
}
```

This is allowed in Java and works without any issue. But let's say in another package you declare

```
A b = new B();
int z = b.foo(5);
```

Then this won't work because obviously A foo() is protected. But then why allow in the first place to have more accessible methods in the subclasses? Is there a case where this is helpful?

Comment: Why forbid it ? Privacy of subclasses can't be really enforced: if you want you could just create another method exporting the value.

Comment: It's simply Liskov Substitution Principle: the subclass can be more permissive in who it allows to invoke the method, because it is at least as permissive as the superclass.

Answer (score 3):

In general, subclasses can add methods to the interface they inherit from their parent class. Making a method more accessible is effectively adding to the interface.

> But then why allow in the first place to have more accessible methods in the subclasses?

Because it can be useful for code that holds a subclass reference.

> Is there a case where this is helpful?

One good example is `Object.clone()`, a protected method. All Java classes are subclasses, directly or indirectly, of `Object`. Subclasses that support cloning can choose to make this method public.

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo();
Foo foo2 = foo1.clone(); // Sometimes you're holding a subclass reference.
```

Comment: the general example about `clone` is not bad, 1+, but *generally* that method should have been in `Cloneable`; a terrible idea to have it in `Object` IMO

Comment: @Eugene - Yes, definitely the Cloneable interface should have included a clone() method. [See more discussion in Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*: "Override `clone` judiciously".] As a separate matter, it was useful to provide a default implementation somewhere supporting a field-by-field copy. The protected Object member provides a default implementation for optional use by subclasses. Regardless whether the Object method had been called `clone()` or something else, subclasses can choose to provide a public clone() method.

Comment: `clone()` is bad designed because it relies on widening access modifier of `Object.clone()` in subclasses. So I don't think that `clone()` is a good example why we may use widening access modifier. It is rather the reverse : a good example why we should not use it.

Comment: @davidxxx - You've asserted that, both here and in your answer, but have not demonstrated a harmful effect. Your assertion that it leads to something "that will fail only at runtime" does not appear to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Because classing is supposed to allow you to think of subclasses as instances of their superclasses. I think this is called an `is-a` relationship (namely `B is-a A`, but not the other way around). I don't really know a good way to explain this succinctly.

In your example, all instances of `B` are also instances of `A` (be mindful this may be a gross oversimplifaction, but I think for this example it is enough). `A` only guarantees to have methods that are public in its own definition. `B` just happens to make one of the protected methods `public`, but let's suppose you had another class called `C` that did not do this. Well, you can cast both `B` and `C` into `A`, but if you were allowed to call the protected method on `A` because `B` makes it public, then you would get an error when you pass `C`.

In the other package, you're casting `B` to `A`, so your object effectively takes on the interface of `A` so you are restricted to use only the interface given to you by `A`. Can the JVM go through the trouble and notice that 1) `A` is in fact `B` and that 2) `B` makes `foo` public, so `foo` should be callable? I mean it could I suppose, but how much effort would that take to implement in the JVM and how error prone would that be? Keep it simple. If the type is `A`, then the interface is `A`. If the type is `B`, then the interface is `A` and whatever else `B` includes on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* make the second example compile if you replaced `A` with `B`.  That's the point: B can be used everywhere A can, but can also add additional features (such as making methods public).